# Allow access my website from my specific another website only in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Suppose I have 2 website #1) domain1.com and #2) domain2.com

I want that only domain1.com visitor can visit domain2.com other websites like example.com can't visit my website. 
When they visit it show error :)

```
<Limit GET POST> Deny from all Allow from domain1.com </limit>
```

I also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://movienoe.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `order deny,allow`, put this into your `.htaccess`:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from domain1.com
```

This will deny everyone access unless they visit via `domain1.com`

You can then redirect the users who're not coming from `domain1.com` to another page of your choosing, I've put in a 404 page just as an example, but you can change this to whatever you like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.domain2.com/404.html [L,R,NE]
```

For Apache 2.4:

You can use an IF directive since you're using 2.4:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.domain1.com'">
Redirect / http://www.domain2.com/404.html
</If>
```

and for the order deny,allow you would use:

```
Require all denied
Require host domain1.com
```